# Print a character frequencies as a vertical graph

Tags: beginner, c

I've been solving K&R 1-14.

> **Exercise 1-14.** Write a program to print a histogram of the frequencies of different characters in its input.

After several edits, it looks good to me now. But it's my first time to write a long code(it's long to me). I wonder if there is more simple and shorter code with the same logic or I wrote a bad style code or not. I also wonder whether my vertical graph looks good and well written.  Any suggestion will be so appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*  print a graph of the frequencies of different characters */

#define GRAPH_HEIGHT 20

main()
{
    int af[26] = {0};
    int max = 1;
    int c;
    int i, j;

    /* get characters */
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') 
            if (++af[c - 'a'] > max) {
                ++max;
                continue;
            }
        if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
            if (++af[c - 'A'] > max)
                ++max;
    }

    /* calculate a relative frequencies */
    for (i = 0; i < 26; ++i) {
        af[i] = GRAPH_HEIGHT * af[i] / max;
    }

    /* print characters on a graph */
    for (i = GRAPH_HEIGHT; i > 0; --i) {
        printf("%2d |", i);
        for (j = 'a'; j <= 'z'; ++j) {
            if (af[j - 'a'] == i) {
                printf(" | ");
                --af[j - 'a'];
            }
            else
                printf("   ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("   " "*" "---------------" "---------------" "---------------" "---------------" "---------------" "---"  "\n");
    printf("   ");
    for (i = 'a'; i <= 'z'; ++i) {
        printf("%3c", i);
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a pretty good start.  You should be warned that K&R describes a very early version of C, and the language has evolved considerably since the 1980s.

For example, we normally always write function declarations as *prototypes*, i.e. specifying the argument types, and we don't depend on the implicit `int`.  So:

```
int main(void)
```

Also, we don't need to declare all variables at the start of their scope any more; instead, we can declare them where they are initialised:

```
for (int i = 0;  i < 26;  ++i)
```

Although the problem statement says that you should chart the frequency of different characters, we have implemented something different here, because we're only counting the characters between `a` and `z` and between `A` and `Z`.

While looking at that, there's a non-portable assumption in this code that `'Z'-'A'` and `'z'-'a'` are both 25.  That is true on ASCII systems, but definitely not true on EBCDIC systems, for example, where this code will index `af` outside its bounds.

You could solve this by declaring `af` differently:

```
#define AZ_COUNT ('z' - 'a' + 1)
unsigned int af[AZ_COUNT] = {0};
```

I think I would store counts of all different characters, and filter to just the alphabetic ones later (and use `isalpha()` for that, from `<ctype.h>`):

```
#include <limits.h>
unsigned int af[UCHAR_MAX+1] = {0};
```

That can make it easier to adapt the printing part (e.g. to show digits and punctuation characters) later.  (Note the use of `unsigned int`, too - a negative count makes no sense).

I think the printing part would be better if it didn't modify the counts.  We can ensure that if we split the counting and printing into separate functions:

```
void count_chars(FILE *in, unsigned int *frequencies);
void print_graph(FILE *out, const unsigned int *frequencies);
```

That `const` helps us write code that's more reusable.

---

With my changes, the code looks more like this (not perfect, but I hope it has some items to learn from):

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/*  print a graph of the frequencies of different characters */

#define GRAPH_HEIGHT 20

static void count_chars(FILE *in, unsigned int *frequencies)
{
    int c;
    while ((c = fgetc(in)) != EOF) {
        ++frequencies[(unsigned char)c];
    }
}

static void print_graph(FILE *out, const unsigned int *frequencies)
{
    /* start at 1 to avoid division by 0 later */
    unsigned int max = 1;
    for (unsigned int i = 0;  i <= UCHAR_MAX;  ++i) {
        if (frequencies[i] > max) {
            max = frequencies[i];
        }
    }

    /* print characters on a graph */
    for (unsigned int i = GRAPH_HEIGHT;  i > 0;  --i) {
        fprintf(out, "%2d |", i);
        for (int c = 0;  c <= UCHAR_MAX;  ++c) {
            if (!isalnum(c)) { continue; }
            char bar = frequencies[c] >= i * max / GRAPH_HEIGHT ? '|' : ' ';
            fprintf(out, " %c ", bar);
        }
        fputs("\n", out);
    }

    /* print the base line */
    fputs("   +", out);
    for (int c = 0;  c <= UCHAR_MAX;  ++c) {
        if (!isalnum(c)) { continue; }
        fputs("---", out);
    }
    fputs("\n", out);
    for (int c = 0;  c <= UCHAR_MAX;  ++c) {
        if (!isalnum(c)) { continue; }
        fprintf(stdout, "%3c", c);
    }
    fputs("\n", out);
}

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int af[UCHAR_MAX+1] = {0};
    count_chars(stdin, af);
    print_graph(stdout, af);
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the detailed answer. I enjoyed your code by freely modifying it.
Anyway, I have one question. I saw the CS50 course and a professor said "It's just human convention to put the main program at the top". You put the main() at the bottom. Is there a special reason to that? In order not to type the function prototype?

Comment: I have to admit I'm not even consistent whether I start with bare prototypes and `main()`, or write definitions and put `main()` last.  Do it whichever way you're happy with!

Comment: I've made an edit, to declare the helpers with *static linkage*.  That makes no perceptible difference for single-file programs like this, but helps keep concerns separate when you get to bigger programs comprising multiple object files.